# List Computers with a Specific Folder Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, inventory

I am trying to create an inventory of AD Computers which have the Test version of a program installed.  The program does not create an entry in Windows Programs list, it simply creates a folder inside of the Public user folder.  For a number of reasons, it would be nice if I could just poll AD to get the list of computers to then search for the "Test" folder inside Public user.

This is what I came up with, but of course it fails because I am a newb.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\Users\Public\Program\Test | Export-Csv \\computer\Users\Daren\Desktop\testfolder.csv
```

This is a better script someone wrote after posting this question on another board, but the output is blank and they have not told me how to fix it.

```
$computers = get-adcomputer -filter *

$output = @()

ForEach ($computer in $computers) {

If(Test-Path -Path "\\$($computer.Name)\c$\Users\Public\path\test") {

    $output += $computer

    }

}

$output | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path .\test.csv
```

All input is welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
get-adcomputer -filter * | foreach-object {
  $computerName = $_.Name
  if ( test-path "\\$computerName\C$\Users\Public\path\test" ) {
    $computerName
  }
} | out-file list.txt
```

Alternatively:

```
get-adobject -ldapfilter "(objectClass=computer)" | foreach-object {
  $computerName = $_.Name
  if ( test-path "\\$computerName\C$\Users\Public\path\test" ) {
    $computerName
  }
}
```

Comment: Bill, thank you very much for your speedy reply!!  I am testing now and will report my findings.

Comment: The output file is blank again!  I am very confused.

Comment: This is the error I got:

get-adcomputer : The server has returned the following error:   invalid enumeration context.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-adcomputer -filter * | foreach-object {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

Comment: @Dazza - try alternative answer.

Comment: Bill, your help is greatly appreciated, however I get a similar error as before:

get-adobject : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-adobject -ldapfilter "(objectClass=computer)" | foreach-object {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject

Comment: In that case you will need to search using the .NET DirectorySearcher object which gives you greater flexibility in how to conduct the search.

Comment: That is not a technology I have worked with before.  I guess I can start now.